# Asymptotic expansion of the solution of $f_n(x)=x^5+nx-1=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, asymptotics, roots

Let's call $u_n$ the solution (it is unique) of $f_n(x)=x^5+nx-1=0$. I'd like to find an asymptotic expansion of $u_n$ of order two. I found $$u_n=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^6}+o(\frac{1}{n^6})$$

The method I used:

- We have $0 < u_n < 1$, hence $0 < n u_n =1-u_n^5 < 1$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} u_n = 0$.
- Therefore $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} u_n^5 = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} nu_n = 1$, which provides the first term of the development.
- I followed with $v_n=u_n-\frac{1}{n}$ to get $(v_n+\frac{1}{n})^5+n v_n=0$. I proved that $0 < 1+ n v_n <1$ and followed to get the second term.

Somehow tedious...

**I there a more systematic approach using calculus?**

Comment: What about applying Newton's method till two consecutive approximations differ by less than the wanted error? Not very different from your fixed-point approach, anyway.

Comment: This is mechanized in Maple. For example, see the three-terms asymptotics: $${n}^{-1}-{n}^{-6}+5\,{n}^{-11}+O \left( {n}^{-16} \right) . $$

Comment: @user64494. My question is in fact how is it mechanized!

Comment: @ mathcounterexamples.net : Do you want to know how your calculator finds $\sqrt{29.78}?$

Comment: @user64494. Not precisely. I know it is usually based on finding an initial approximation and then using Newton's iterative method $u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(u_n+\frac{29.78}{u_n})$. But not the details to be honest!

Comment: @user64494 I don't have Maple installed. Is Maple able to compute the asymptotic expansion for any function $f_n(x)$?

Comment: @ mathcounterexamples.net                                                                             1. In most cases Pade approximants are used to calculate  values of  elementary functions.  2. No, of course, not.

Comment: @user64494 OK thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange the equation like

$$
\frac{x}{1-x^5} = \frac{1}{n}.
$$

The hypotheses of the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) are satisfied, giving us the formula

$$
x = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \left\{ \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{k-1} (1-x^5)^k \right\}_{x=0} n^{-k},
$$

valid as long as $|n|$ is large enough.  The first terms of this series are

$$
x = n^{-1} - n^{-6} + 5n^{-11} - 35n^{-16} + 285n^{-21} - 2530n^{-26} + 23751 n^{-31} + \cdots.
$$

Comment: Thanks Antonio. Is there a proof of Lagrange inversion theorem in the book you mentionned in the other post: Bruijn's Asymptotic Methods in Analysis?

Comment: No, it doesn't have a proof, only applications of the formula.  The wikipedia page points to a book which does, though.

Comment: I think the above expansion is found by CASs because   the derivatives are huge.

Comment: @user64494 yes, I used Mathematica to evaluate the derivatives.

Answer (score 7):

To compute the asymptotic expansion of $x$ by first principle, 
the proper way is to use the [Lagrange Inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) as mentioned in another answer. 
I won't repeat it here. I'll like to point out
this $x$ is closed related to something well studied.

Let $x = n^{1/4} y$, we have
$$x^5 + nx - 1 = 0 \quad\iff\quad y^5 + y - n^{-5/4} = 0$$ 
The RHS has the form of a [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical),

$$\verb/BR(a)/ \stackrel{def}{=} \text{ root of } t^5 + t + a \text{ which is real when } a \text{ is real }$$

It is well known one can express the Bring radical in terms of 
[Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).
If you look at Bring radical's wiki entry and the expansion there, you will find
$$\begin{align}
x 
&= n^{1/4}\verb/BR/(-n^{-5/4})\\
&= \frac{1}{n}{}_4F_3\left(\frac15,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45;\;\;\frac12, \frac34, \frac54;\;\;-\frac{5^5}{4^4 n^5}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{5k}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(4k+1)n^{5k+1}}
\end{align}
$$
The expansion is not only asymptotic, it actually converges when 
$\displaystyle\;|n| > \frac{4^{4/5}}{5}$.