# The question about asymptotic expansion of the solution of $x^5+nx-1=0$.

Tags: asymptotics, roots

There is the question and answer about it there: [Asymptotic expansion of the solution of $f_n(x)=x^5+nx-1=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423192/asymptotic-expansion-of-the-solution-of-f-nx-x5nx-1-0).

But what is about formal computation?

Suppose that $x = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k n^{-k}$.
Then I can substitute $x$ in the equation by this series and obtain the correct answer.
But I have no idea about validity of this computation :(

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Achille Hui's answer to the other question, mentioning the Bring radical, looks pretty formal to me.

Comment: Hmm, I can write a series, substitute $x$ and compute coefficients. I do not care about any topology, convergence etc.

Comment: Citing Achille Hui: *"The expansion is not only asymptotic, it actually converges when $\ldots$"*

Comment: Ok, but this method using some hyperheomtric function and specific equation type. For exmaple I can consider $x^{2k+1} +nx -1=0$ and do the same thing. I asked why does it work? To obtain an answer using "substitution" method mentioned above I do not need any extra knowledge.

Comment: It works because the hypergeometric function associated to the solution is an analytic function with a positive radius of convergence, hence the "substitution" method actually works.

Comment: But it is not clear how it works. Notion of Bring radical is only for equation with $x^5$. Or it can be generalized?

Comment: @Alex-omsk Did you mention this question to the author of the answer it discusses? If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

If you let $$x=\sum_{k=1}^p {a_k}\,{n^{-k}}$$ expand

$$\Bigg(\sum _{k=1}^p a_k\, n^{-k}\Bigg)^5+\sum _{k=1}^p a_k\, n^{-k+1}-1=0$$ and identify the coefficients (one at the time).

To order $O\left(\frac{1}{n^{21}}\right)$, the coefficients are
$$\{1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,-35,0,0,0,0\}$$ that is to say

$$x_{(21)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^6}+\frac{5}{n^{11}}-\frac{35}{n^{16}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{21}}\right)$$ the $21^{\text{st}}$ coefficent is not $0$.

Plugged in the equation
$$x^5+n x-1=-\frac{285}{n^{20}}$$

Try it for $n=100$; it would give

$$x=\frac{199999999980000000009999999993}{20000000000000000000000000000000}$$ which is
$$x=\color{red}{0.009999999999000000000499999999650000000}000$$

while the solution is

$$x=0.009999999999000000000499999999650000000285$$